# Is there a bug in the "IO.inspect spec" explanation?

Tags: elixir

In the [IO.inspect doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2), the first parameter is item, the second parameter is options.

```
inspect(item, opts \\ [])
@spec inspect(
  item,
  keyword()
) :: item
when item: var
```

the `item` has no link for further explanation and keyword's link seems the item's built-in explanation, and not for option's explanation.

Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug here. Typespecs provide a [guard syntax](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#defining-a-specification), using `when`, which is useful for generic functions that work with any type but can express a type constraint between several arguments or the return value.

This spec should be read as "`IO.inspect(x, opts)` will have the same type as `x`". `item` isn't a type, but a variable expressing this constraint.

`when item: var` means that `item` can just be of any type:

> Type variables with no restriction can also be defined using `var`.

`options` explanations isn't covered by the typespec, but by the doc itself:

> See [`Inspect.Opts`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html) for a full list of remaining formatting options.